# create a Pseudo command for lampp xampp

Tags: command-line, bash, lamp, xampp

How do I create a psuedo command for the terminal?

The basic command for lampp is:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

But I don't want to type this every time so can I create a psuedo for this so I can just type

```
lampp start
lampp startssl
lampp stop
```

and so forth so that lampp invokes sudo `/opt/lampp/lampp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and create aliases.

It's quite simple, just add lines such as:

```
alias lstart="sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start"
```

Be careful when creating your aliases because you may create an alias which is name the same as something that already exists. Also, do not delete anything else in that file or your may find things breaking.

Comment: Is these any way to check if my alias command already exist ? to avoid any conflict like this you have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Please type the below commmands after starting a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
gedit ~/bashrc
```

go to the end of the file and add the following alias to the standard `lampp` command:

```
lampp(){ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp "$@" ;}
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close gedit.

This will bring you back to the terminal which you exit and re-open again. if you're on a `TTY` you need to type:

```
 source ~/bashrc
```

Now you can use the `lammp` command normally, but as aliases get executed before normal commands, it'll look like you type `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp` every time you just type `lampp`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1068144/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**